# RimWorld - Which objects stack

Tags: rimworld

Today while playing rimworld I noticed that hay was stacking in more than 75.
I don't know the limits about Hay.
[image]

So, I was just curious to know which objects stack more than 75?

I know that silver, Jade and hay do. Are there any others?

Comment: Not related, but heads up: unsmoothed stone walls make the pawns unhappy. Smooth them with the "smooth surface" tool, or alternatively, you could save on work needed by breaking it down and build new walls.

Comment: However, smoothened stuff raise the colony wealth and thus the raid points considerably.

Answer (score 5):

A limited number of items can be stacked above the 75x limit. These items can be found by looking at the [Rimworld Wiki](http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Materials) and selecting the different types of items you want to view.

A quick glance shows that Gold, Silver, Uranium, Jade and Hay are stackable above 75.